# .pyc extention Django Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I was reading that .pyc contain byte code, which is what the Python interpreter compiles the source to. This code is then executed by Python's virtual machine.

Hoever, since I'm learning Django for the first time and coming from Node.js it's a little different, everytime I type on my terminal python manage.py runserver it creates multiple versions of the same file but in .pyc format, which by the definition I'm guessing that's the compiled version so it's faster, but I think it's too many files, is that normal? What if don't want to compile it to have all those extra files? I'm learning python and Django for the first time, could someone clarify this a little please. Here is a picture of what I mean with the extra files:

[image]

Also in the tutorial that I' following they have

```
from django.conf.urls import path,
```

and the new version of Django has

```
from django.conf.urls import url,
```

just want to make sure, they are the same right?

Thank you

Comment: No the are not the same.

Comment: As for the `.pyc` files, these are frequently stored in a separate directory named `__pycache__`.

Comment: thanks, but why am I seeing them all together between my code? I makes the files hard to read, and that's only the beginning of a simple app

Comment: how do you run your system? With what flags/settings/...?

Comment: At least since Python-3.2, a `__pycache__` directory is created by default.

Comment: I'm runnning the code inside VSCode, could it be the reason why it's creating all those files inside? I have the terminal integraded there

Comment: What editor is that? Usually they can be configured to ignore things like .pyc files.

Comment: It's Visual Studio Code

Comment: Based on what you told me I deleted the files on the folder (the .pyc) and ran the code in a separate terminal, and it created this time a folder called `_pycache_` just like you said :) Thank you very much! I have to find out now how can it be done with the intergrated terminal on Visual Studio Code :)

Comment: @Arturo: If you do not want such files, you can run the interpreter with the `-B` flag, but this will typically be a bit slower (well not magnitudes, but a some percentages).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks, what I'm doing is running it in the separete terminal, I don't mind it for now, I want to keep moving forward and leave the VSC problem for another time. Thanks Will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its better to not show those `.pyc` file in the sidebar. You can do that by putting the following line in the [user/workspace settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).

```
"files.exclude": {
    "**/*.pyc": true
},
```